# error with arules::read.transactions(): "'cols' does not match entries in header of file" even though they do match

Tags: r, arules

I have a text file like the following:

```
transactionID item
T100 l1,l2,l3
T200 l2,l4
T300 l2,l3
T400 l1,l2,l3
T500 l1,l3
T600 l2,l3
T700 l1,l3
T800 l1,l2,l3,l5
T900 l1,l2,l3
```

And I would like to read it as a transaction file for arules.
I used the following:

```
transacciones <- read.transactions(file = "/home/norhther/Escritorio/trans.txt",
                                   format = "single",
                                   sep = ",",
                                   header = TRUE,
                                   cols = c("transactionID", "item"),
                                   rm.duplicates = TRUE)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error in read.transactions(file = "/home/norhther/Escritorio/trans.txt", : 
'cols' does not match entries in header of file.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

You should change your format to `basket` and use a separator of `sep = " "` with `cols = 1` like this:

```r
text = 'transactionID item
T100 l1,l2,l3
T200 l2,l4
T300 l2,l3
T400 l1,l2,l3
T500 l1,l3
T600 l2,l3
T700 l1,l3
T800 l1,l2,l3,l5
T900 l1,l2,l3'

write(text, file = "trans.txt")

library(arules)
transacciones <- read.transactions(file = "~/Downloads/trans.txt",
                                   format = "basket",
                                   sep = " ",
                                   skip = 1,
                                   cols = c(1),
                                   rm.duplicates = TRUE)

inspect(transacciones)
#>     items         transactionID
#> [1] {l1,l2,l3}    T100         
#> [2] {l2,l4}       T200         
#> [3] {l2,l3}       T300         
#> [4] {l1,l2,l3}    T400         
#> [5] {l1,l3}       T500         
#> [6] {l2,l3}       T600         
#> [7] {l1,l3}       T700         
#> [8] {l1,l2,l3,l5} T800         
#> [9] {l1,l2,l3}    T900
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

According to the documentation of the function [`read.transactions`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/arules/versions/1.6-1/topics/read.transactions), you can use the argument `cols`:

> For the single format, cols is a numeric or character vector of length
> two giving the numbers or names of the columns (fields) with the
> transaction and item ids, respectively. If character, the first line
> of file is assumed to be a header with column names. For the basket
> format, cols can be a numeric scalar giving the number of the column
> (field) with the transaction ids. If cols = NULL, the data do not
> contain transaction ids.

So you can specify your columns by numeric vector like `c(1,2)`. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
text = 'transactionID item
T100 l1,l2,l3
T200 l2,l4
T300 l2,l3
T400 l1,l2,l3
T500 l1,l3
T600 l2,l3
T700 l1,l3
T800 l1,l2,l3,l5
T900 l1,l2,l3'
cat(text)
#> transactionID item
#> T100 l1,l2,l3
#> T200 l2,l4
#> T300 l2,l3
#> T400 l1,l2,l3
#> T500 l1,l3
#> T600 l2,l3
#> T700 l1,l3
#> T800 l1,l2,l3,l5
#> T900 l1,l2,l3
write(text, file = "trans.txt")

library(arules)
transacciones <- read.transactions(file = "~/Downloads/trans.txt", # Change to your own directory
                                   format = "single",
                                   sep = ",",
                                   header = TRUE,
                                   cols = c(1, 2),
                                   rm.duplicates = TRUE)

inspect(transacciones)
#>     items transactionID
#> [1] {l2}  T100 l1      
#> [2] {l4}  T200 l2      
#> [3] {l3}  T300 l2      
#> [4] {l2}  T400 l1      
#> [5] {l3}  T500 l1      
#> [6] {l3}  T600 l2      
#> [7] {l3}  T700 l1      
#> [8] {l2}  T800 l1      
#> [9] {l2}  T900 l1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Still not reading properly the items in the transaction, i.e, the items in the first row should be `l1,l2,l3`

Comment: Hi @Norhther, And if you try adding ‘skip=1’ in the function?

Comment: Hi @Norhther, I added some changes to the code.